# How to make Windows use D:/ instead of C:/ for Users and AppData folder?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, filesystems

My C:/ (system volume) is getting fast filled. I am looking to see the following options.

1) Move Users folder (profile folder location) to D:/. Is this possible even? 2) Can we also attempt to have Windows use D:/AppData instead of C:/AppData?

Comment: Windows 7 does not have a `C:\AppData` folder.

Comment: @DavidPostill Public Appdata is C:\ProgramData. I'm pretty sure he means that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a folder like the profiles folder is going to be hard if you attempt to reconstruct windows to use the new path.

So the easiest option would be to move the folder, and then at the original location create a symbolic link (directory junction) to the new location.

This way, windows will still look for its stuff in C:\Users, but gets redirected to D:\Users and it no longer fills your harddrive.

The only problem is that the C:\Users folder is in use, so you can only perform this action while not in windows. This means that you either have to move your harddrive(s) to a different pc or even better, use something like Hirens Boot CD which has a mini windows version in which it will work. Windows 8 and 10 both have a repair option which gives you access to a command prompt. That'll work too.

I'm not sure if booting into safemode with command prompt only works so I can't comment on that. It might, but its not guaranteed.

I recommend to first copy all the data from C:\Users to D:\Users, so all security settings remain in tact. You will need Administrative Privileges for this action though.

Now, start a command prompt with administrative privileges and type the following commands while in C:\

```
move C:\Users C:\Users_old

mklink /j Users D:\Users
```

If you booted from hirens boot dvd your C drive is likely a different letter, such as E:, F:, etc. Find out what the actual letter is first and use that instead, so Move C:\Users becomes Move e:\users e:\users_old.

If for some reason things don't work as expected, you can simply undo this by removing the c:\Users and renaming the C:\Users_Old back. Only delete the C:\Users_old until you are sure everything works correctly.

The above can of course also be done using C:\ProgramData

Comment: I''m pretty certain I've seen advice not to do this because it can break windows updates.

Comment: **WARNING**: Windows can (and probably will) attempt to restore these “special” folders, replacing the symlink in the process. This can kill Windows completely. I once had a similar problem when I moved the Visual Studio folder to another drive. An update for VS decided to “restore” the directory (not completely, of course). I had to reinstall Windows to make VS work again.

Comment: @DanielB Yeah, it doesn't work with Program Files unless you alter the registry, but Users and programdata work without a problem. Also Windows does not attempt to restore these symlinks. The only reason it wants to do this is with a major update.